# How does expanding by Taylor's theorem work here?

Tags: group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

### The problem

I am trying to figure out a step in the proof of this [book](https://archive.org/details/designforbrainor00ashb) (p. 245), where it goes like this:

> \begin{equation}\tag{a}\label{eq:equal} F_i(x^0; t + dt) = F_i(x; dt)\end{equation}
>   Expand by Taylor's theorem and write $\frac{\delta}{\delta b}F_i(a; b)$ as $F'_i(a;b)$. 
>   Then
>   \begin{equation}\tag{b}\label{eq:taylor} F_i(x^0;t) + dt. F'_i(x^0;t) = F_i(x; 0) + dt. F'_i(x;0)\end{equation}

### Background

Few things are required to be explained before the above can make any sense.

1. $x$ is a vector of time-dependent variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ (i.e. each $x_i(t)$ being a function of t).
2. $x^0$ is an initial state.
3. $F_i$ is a function that produces the next state of $x_i$ given the state and elapsed time $t$. So:$$x_i = F_i(x^0_1, ..., x^0_n; t)$$ So, for example, if no time is passed, for $F_1$ we just have: $x^0_1 = F_1(x^0_1, ..., x^0_n;t)$.
4. In the problem above the system is:

   - 4.1. Started at $x^0_1, ..., x^0_n$ at $t=0$.
   - 4.2. At time $t$ it changes to $x_1, ..., x_n$
   - 4.3. At time $t+dt$ it changes to $x_1 + dx, ..., x_n + dx$.

   Also, it is proved that if started at $x_1, ..., x_n$ at $t=0$ and $dt$ is elapsed, we arrive at the same final state as at the end of #4.3. (This has to do with $F_i$'s forming a group). In notation of #1: $x^0_i$ changes to $F_i(x^0; t+dt)$, while $x_i$ changes to $F_i(x;dt)$. Which leads to Equation$\eqref{eq:equal}$ above.

### Questions

Here are some of the quesitons I have (I am not a mathematician, so sorry if they are too basic):

1. What does the notation $dt.$ (with the period following) mean here? I've been trying to figure out whether it's a derivative or a delta of t. Any ideas?
2. How is it that Taylor's theorem applied to Equation \eqref{eq:equal} here? I have no idea how Equation \eqref{eq:taylor} is arrived at. Could someone explain it to me in baby steps?

P.S.: No idea what to tag it as, hopefully someone can fix the tags if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expanding the function $F_i(x^0;t+dt)$ to Taylor series around the point $t$. Then it follows

$$F_i(x^0;t+dt) = F_i(x^0;t) + ((t+dt)-t) \frac{F_i'(x^0;t)}{1!} + ((t+dt)-t)^2 \frac{F_i''(x^0;t)}{2!} + \dots$$

which looks like a discretization of a continuous time dynamical system with sampling period $dt$ in your case. This holds in general, but you took only the first component so it is a very approximate model. But you cannot use this approximation if the system is unstable.

In (a) you are assuming that your system is time-invariant.

Comment: Thank you! And [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) has a similar explanation of this (Eq. 27).

Answer (score 1):

$dt$ is a time increment, you could as well write $h$ or $\tau$ or $\Delta t$.

Looks like some relation for the flow of an autonomous dynamical system where you get to the same point if you start at $x(0)=x_0$ and advance in time $t+Δt$ or if you start at $x=x(t)$ and advance only the missing time $Δt$.

The dot is a regional variant or a careless shorthand for the multiplication dot.

---

Looking at the source, this is exactly what is described. You are given an autonomous ODE 
$$\dot x=f(x),$$ 
where $x$ is the state vector, and obtain for it the flow $F(x_0,t)$ which is the general solution to the initial value problem $x(0)=x_0$ at time $t$.

By the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, solutions exist and are unique, so you get the group property
$$F(F(x_0,s),t)=F(x_0,s+t),$$ 
that is, restarting the initial value problem at some point on the trajectory of a first solution just continues that solution. In other words, if $x(t)=F(x_0,t)$ and $\tilde x(0)=x(s)$, and both $x$ and $\tilde x$ are solutions of the ODE, then 
$$\tilde x(t)=x(s+t).$$

---

Since as a solution trajectory $∂_t F(x_0,t)=f(F(x_0,t))$, which at $t=0$ reduces to $∂_t F(x_0,0)=f(x_0)$ the equation for the group identity in the book can also be read as without using Taylor polynomials:

$$∂_t F(F(x_0,s),t)|_{t=0} =f(F(x_0,s))=∂_t F(x_0,t)|_{t=s}=∂_t F(x_0,s+t)|_{t=0}$$

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful to know what the equivalent modern terminology is! One more silly question though, how does the Taylor theorem fit into here? I.e. what is it's purpose?

Comment: It is not really needed, just a complicated way to reintroduce the differential equation in the proof of the flow group identity.